# Sony Xperia Z1 with Arduino Mega ADK

Tags: sony

I'm trying to develop a small android app which can communicate with Arduino Mega ADK board to control a LED. I have a Sony Xperia Z1 and the app I made is works in mobile without any problem. But when I connect the Arduino board to the Z1, there is nothing happen. I'm wondering is it possible to do such a project with Z1 or do I have to use a Google Nexus phone for this task. ?

Comment: Thanks Sri. Actually I got my problem sorted.  Problem was not with my Xperia z1. There was a error with accessory_filter.xml file. The fields I entered wasn't tallied with the arduino coding.  Now my program is working super nicely.  Thanks sri.

Answer (score 0):

It will work %100 sure but it adds extra cost of adapter($3-4). ADK board brings an extra set of features for communication with Android. This *may* cut the cost of adapter, although not %100 sure. To be on the safe side, go to this page for details: http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html.

Xperia Z1 would work with an ADK board just like any other Android smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with either the Arduino IDE configuration or the Eclipse/Android Studio Configuration. I was in your shoes for the past one month. I wrote a blog explaining everything in detail which worked for me. Hope this helps.

http://blog.srichakram.in/2015/09/arduino-mega-adk-and-android.html